# jQuery: Find and replace all attributes

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm attempting to replace a specific portion of the input id's attribute and the label for's attribute within each(). However, when I check the rendering, only the input id's attribute has changed to id="something_else_[name]", but the label for's attribute is left unchanged as for="id_target_[name]".

What am I doing wrong?

jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    $('.target').each( function() { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('id_target','something_else'));
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="target">
<input id="id_target_Bob" type="checkbox">
<label for="id_target_Bob">Target Bob</label>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="target">
<input id="something_else_Bob" type="checkbox">
<label for="id_target_Bob">Target Bob</label> <!-- why is this left unchanged? -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.replace` only replaces the *first* instance of the search string.  If you want to replace all instances, you must use a regex with the `g` (global) flag:

```
.replace(/id_target/g, 'something_else')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/cV6pw/

Answer (score 3):

You can just update the attributes.  This will find all input and label tags within your target div and replace their attributes:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="target">
  <input id="id_target_Bob" type="checkbox">
  <label for="id_target_Bob">Target Bob</label>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.target').each(function () {         
        $('input').attr('id', 'something_else');
        $('label').attr('for', 'something_else');
    });
});
```

**Tip:**

For better performance, you should always prefix your class with the tag it belongs to.  The second fastest selector in jQuery is the Tag selector because it maps to a native Javascript method, `getElementsByTagName()`.

Instead of using `$('.target').each(function () {...`, do `$('div.target').each(function () {...`

Answer (score 2):

regex `g` is what you need here

try this

```
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/id_target/g,'something_else'));
```

Answer (score 1):

because it is replacing only the first occurrence as you told the script to do so

you need to use `/id_target/g` so that it will replace all occurrence it finds & not just the first one